# OS X - Setting (and keeping) new anchorPoint on MKAnnotationView's layer

Tags: objective-c, macos, animation, mkannotationview

I am working on an OS X map app that would benefit from annotation clustering, and have adopted this approach, written for iOS: [TBAnnotationClustering](https://github.com/thoughtbot/TBAnnotationClustering) into a Mac OS version: [TBAnnotationClustering (Mac)](https://github.com/mattwelch/TBAnnotationClustering).

Things work pretty well, except for the bounce-in animation for the annotations. In the iOS project, the animation nicely originates at the center of the annotation. In my Mac version, the animation originates from the upper left corner. This is frustrating, but not unexpected, given CALayer's different default anchorPoint in OS X.

My problem is that I can't seem to permanently change this anchorPoint. I originally tried to set it to (0.5,0.5) in the init method of the AnnotationView, but it wouldn't "stick", and by the time I called the animation, it was back to (0,0). My solution now, which is to reapply the anchorPoint change right before the animation, in addition to being ugly, doesn't completely work, since the first time an annotation is used (and not dequeued), it still bounces in from the upper left.

Another strange data point: In the original iOS version, if I change the anchorPoint to (0,0) in the annotation view's init, it actually sticks, and the animation comes in from the upper left, as expected. It seems odd that the anchorPoint change would stick around in iOS and not OS X.

Main question:
How can I set and maintain the anchorPoint for the annotation view's layer?

And some bonus questions, for my edification:

My understanding is that I have to set wantsLayer to YES to get a layer-backed view in OS X. Is this not the case for annotation views? Do they automatically get a layer to back them?

My further understanding is that we're specifically NOT supposed to be messing with the anchorPoint property of layers in layer-backed views, per [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coreanimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004514-CH3-SW18). So why does this seem like the only option to get a centered animation?

Thanks for any help.